# Rails custom and default routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-routing

I'm trying to define custom routes to my controller and I need to use some of the default routes too. Is there any simple solution?

So far I've something like this

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'users/:id', to: 'users#show'
    delete 'users/:id', to: 'users#destroy'
  end
  collection do 
    post 'users', to: 'users#create'
    post 'users/login', to: 'users#login'
  end
end
resources :users, :only => [:show, :destroy, :create, :login]
```

I don't need nor want the `index` route but with this settings it's still trying to route `GET users/` to `user_controller` `index` method.

I know that there is probably some simple and obvious answer but I'm not able to find it.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: read about [routing in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: I've read whole article but combination of `:only` and `do` block isn't there. This combinations are probably usual in Ruby but I'm not used to it nor able to find example or solution. But anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got your routes wrong. The `resources :users` generates seven default routes which include the `index` route as well. You need to tweak the code to below

```
resources :users, :only => [:show, :destroy, :create] do
  collection do 
    post 'login', to: 'users#login'
  end
end
```

***Note:***

If you noticed, I've removed the **custom routes** for `show`,`create` and `delete` as they are generated by default.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line defines the route to the index action. Define a resource once only. Read the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

```
resources :users, :except => [:index] do
  collection do 
    post 'users/login', to: 'users#login'
  end
end
```

Run `rake routes` from the command line in your project root folder to see all your route definitions.